# MySQL Python Unread Result Found

Tags: python, mysql, mysqlconnector

```
def poses():
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `poses`")
    pose = mycursor.fetchone()
    mycursor.execute("DELETE FROM `poses` WHERE `photo` = %s", (pose[1],))
    bot.send_message(370921204, pose[1])
    bot.send_message(370921204, pose[2])
    mydb.commit()
```

Здраствуйте, возникла такая проблема, что во время удаления данных из БД только что взятых из нее же возникает вот такая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если так? `mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)`

Comment: Раньше пробовал, не выходило, благодарю Вас.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
```